# Error when running hive command on terminal

Tags: hadoop, hive

> /usr/bin/which: no hbase in
> (/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/bin:/home/evirac/.local/bin:/home/evirac/bin:/home/evirac/.local/bin:/home/evirac/bin:/home/evirac/.local/bin:/home/evirac/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/bin:/home/evirac/.local/bin:/home/evirac/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/sbin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/sbin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/sbin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/bin)
> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
> binding in
> [jar:file:/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
> explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
> [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory] Exception in thread
> "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:536)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJarByClass(JobConf.java:554)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.(JobConf.java:448)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:5144)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.(HiveConf.java:5102)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:97)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:81)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)

Comment: it would help if you added the command you used... it seems that hbase command is not found... but the given info cannot help you debug the problem

Comment: Need more info, what did you to that caused this error?

Comment: What happens when you use `beeline` instead?